# Windows 8.1 WinForms C# WebBrowser: Flash Compatibility

Tags: winforms, flash, windows-8, webbrowser-control, windows-8.1

I have a C# WinForms program which runs on Windows 8 but fails on Windows 8.1 (both the beta and the RTM).  I initialize a WebBrowser control with my HTML, which contains an object tag referencing a remote Flash SWF file.  I wish I could switch away from Flash, but this is the only format I can use.

In Windows 8, the file plays fine.  On Windows 8.1, the object tag is successfully written to the page, but it is just a transparent box.  What would have changed in Windows 8.1 that would block Flash in the WebBrowser control?

Here's a link to the code itself.  The program allows for standalone playback of [TWiT.tv](http://twit.tv) programming with the BitGravity player.

http://wessleym.com/twit/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered after some trial-and-error that I needed to have `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"` specified in the `<object>` tag.  Windows 8 worked fine without it, but Windows 8.1 trips up.  My program works great now.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem when our WebControl couldn't start or use Flash Objects. We solved it with Visual Studio 2013. We loaded project in VS2013 and builded it there. Now it works on Windows 8.1 normally.